# Plot Centroid of Specific Blob in C++ OpenCV

Tags: c++, arrays, opencv, image-processing, centroid

I'm trying to plot the centroid of a specific blob detected using contour techniques. I don't wish to loop through all the blob detected in an image - I only want to plot the centroid of one (i.e. contour[2]). Ideally I'd like to accomplish this using the most efficient / fastest method.

Here's my code:

```
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES
#include <math.h>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char** argv)
{
    cv::Mat src = cv::imread("frame-1.jpg");
    if (src.empty())
        return -1;

    cv::Mat gray;
    cv::cvtColor(~src, gray, CV_BGR2GRAY);

    cv::threshold(gray, gray, 160, 255, cv::THRESH_BINARY);

    // Find all contours
    std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point> > contours;
    cv::findContours(gray.clone(), contours, CV_RETR_EXTERNAL, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);

    // Fill holes in each contour
    cv::drawContours(gray, contours, -1, CV_RGB(255, 255, 255), -1);

    cout << contours.size();

    double avg_x(0), avg_y(0); // average of contour points
    for (int j = 0; j < contours[2].size(); ++j)
    {
       avg_x += contours[2][j].x;
       avg_y += contours[2][j].y;
    }

    avg_x /= contours[2].size();
    avg_y /= contours[2].size();
    cout << avg_x << " " << avg_y << endl;

    cv::circle(gray, {avg_x, avg_y}, 5, CV_RGB(5, 100, 100), 5);

    namedWindow("MyWindow", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    imshow("MyWindow", gray);

    waitKey(0);

    destroyWindow("MyWindow");

    return 0;
}
```

However, plotting the circle using the coordinates (avg_x, avg_y) results in a 'no instance of constructor "cv::Point_<*Tp>::Point*[with_Tp=int]" matches the argument list - argument types are: (double, double)' error.

Comment: How do your try to plot the point? It looks like this is not part of your code even though it is the part that gives you the error. Please show the full stack trace of the error AND change your code to a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Check edit - now changed

Comment: http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/moments/moments.html?highlight=moment#code Have you read this? Try to find Moment & centroid for the contour Id 2.

Comment: Yes I have, but as soon as I specify the contour ID I get the same sort of error.

Comment: {avg_x, avg_y} does not construct a cv::Point. you need: `Point(avg_x, avg_y)`

Answer (score 0):

Use min enclosing circle

```
float radius ;
Point2f center ;
minEnclosingCircle ( contours[i] , center , radius ) ; 



cv::circle(gray, center, 5, CV_RGB(5, 100, 100), 5);
```